# kotlin change the value of a var inside a function (SetOnClickListner)

Tags: android, kotlin

I have two buttons btn1 (scan_sac) & btn2 (scan_scelle) and two textviews t1 (ed_idSac) & t2 (ed_scelle). Inside the onClickListner of each button, I will call a function that starts the camera to read a barcode. This camera returns the value of the barcode read in a funtion  onActivityResult; And inside this function (onActivityResult) I am updating the value of one of the two textViews

According to the clicked button I will change the value of the appropriate textview :

- If btn1 is clicked , t1 will be updated
- if btn2 is clicked , t2 will be updated

Now I am stuck at testing which button is clicked to update the appropriate textView. 
I tied to use a boolean Scelle to check which button is clicked.
If scelle is true then scan_scelle (btn2) is clicked

Comment: What's your question? If you don't provide some code it will be difficult to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data:Intent)
```

Use Diffeerent Request Code on click of b1 & b2....

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly you want to know which button is clicked to that you can update proper text view.
A solution would be to have two boolean values for each button, and when the button is pressed you will set that boolean value to true.
Later onActivityResult you can check those boolean values and update proper text views.

Comment: I tired to do that, but the value of the booleans are updated on local ? I defined var pressed : Boolean = false. Inside btn1.OnclickListner pressed = false. But when I check Outside the function, the value of pressed is not updated.

Comment: because inside onClick you need to set that boolean to true.

Comment: Alternatively you could set different request codes for different buttons.

Answer (score 1):

use different `requestCode` for both buttons in your `onActivityResult` method check `requestCode` and place your string to respected `textView`

Answer (score 1):

```
var buttonIdentity :false
val button1= findViewById<Button>(R.id.textview)
button1.setOnClickListener(clickListener)

val button2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
button2.setOnClickListener(clickListener)

val clickListener = View.OnClickListener {view ->

    when (view.getId()) {
        R.id.button1-> buttonIdentity =true
        R.id.button2 -> buttonIdentity  =false
    }
}
```